# How to switch between Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

How going from a second activity to a third or third to a quarter using the click of button. For example I have a main menu with four buttons, each sent me four activities, these four activities have buttons to return to Main menu and go to other three activities.I know how to go from the main activity to another, but I have problems to switch between activities that are not the main activity.
thanks and greetings from the Canary Islands

Comment: Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: there is no difference between going from main to second or from second to third. that's all the same.

Comment: I do not understand I do wrong because when I try to press a button in Activity 2 to go to activity 3 or 3 to 4 fails at runtime

Comment: Without your code and the stacktraces from your logcat errors we cannot help you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your original question with the needed details. Otherwise your question will be closed as "unanswerable".

Answer (score 1):

This is how you start a new `Activity` from an `Activity` with a `Button`:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(Context, NewActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Dont forget to **declare** the new `Activity` in the manifest:

```
<activity
      android:name="your.package.NewActivity"
      android:label="NewActivity" />
```

Comment: using oclick method layout xml running, but does not work using listeners